# SQL - Join 2 tables and calculate running sum (month to date)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There are 2 tables: 
[image]

[image]

Need to join these 2 tables on the same ID and for a date - to show total amount (sum) from beginning of the same month up to (including) date from a first table.

Result should be:
[image]

I made one part (for running sum) but not all yet:

```
  select 
        date_a, a.id,
        sum(b.AMOUNT) over (partition by b.ID, to_varchar(b.ID::date, 'yyyy-mm') 
        order by b.ID) 
        as AMOUNT_MONTH_TO_DATE  
    FROM 
        a
    inner join
        b
    on 
        a.id = b.id
```

Comment: May I know how does the calculation works? If I refer to your expected result, it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Calculation is just a 'note' to myself how to calculate. It is a 4-10 date for id=abc1 (which is 25) + 4-20 date for id=abc1 (which is 30) + 4-30 date for id=abc1 (which is 20). So total is 20+30+25 for this date and same id.

Comment: So for a date of 4-30 - need to take all amounts from a second table from beginning of month 4 for same ID.

Comment: Should abc2 return 10? where as in table_2 date for abc2 is greater than date in table_1.

Comment: I am also wondering about the same thing

Comment: Whatever our predilections for art are away from this site, around here we're generally not too fond of pictures. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Actually SO offered to save my pasting of data as a pic (automatic conversion into a pic) and I jest accepted it.. originally was planning to put pure data..

Comment: @mkRabbani - yes, adjusted second table.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your explanation, abc2 should also return 0 but you shown 10 in your expected output. The reason is date_b is greater than date_a and nothing should be selected for abc2 for the logic date_b between "Start Date of month" and "Date_a". If I am right, this following query will work-

```
SELECT 
A.id,
A.date_a,
COALESCE
(
    (
        SELECT 
        SUM(amount) 
        FROM TABLE_2 B 
        WHERE B.id = A.id 
        AND B.date_b BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,-(DAY(date_a)-1),date_a) AND  A.date_A
    )
    ,0
)
FROM TABLE_1 A
```

The same output can be achieved using LEFT JOIN-

```
SELECT 
A.id,
A.date_a,
COALESCE(SUM(B.amount),0) total_amount
FROM table_1 A
LEFT JOIN table_2 B ON B.id = A.id 
    AND B.date_b BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,-(DAY(A.date_a)-1),date_a) AND  A.date_A
GROUP BY A.id,A.date_a
```

Comment: I think `ISNULL` is suppose to be `IFNULL`? and `Unknown column 'A.RN' in 'field list'`

Comment: Thanks @tcadidot0. RN basically comes from my test script. But I feel ISNULL is ok. Is not it?

Comment: it is a valid MySQL operator but I see that you are trying to make an operation whereby when the sub-query is `NULL` then return '0'. From what I know, `ISNULL(expression)` while `IFNULL(expression,alt_value)`.  And by the way, I also have error at `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-(DAY(date_a)-1)`

Comment: You are welcome @Joe. If it worked, can you please accept the ans :)

Comment: Trying now.. Can you please explain this part: `B.date_b BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,-(DAY(date_a)-1),date_a) AND  A.date_A`.

Comment: Here I just created the start date of the month and checked date fall into the range of start and end date or not.

DATEADD(DD,-(DAY(date_a)-1),date_a) >> Creates the start date for the month date_a

Comment: Thank you.. that is a good logic.. but for this database (Snowflake) getting error for that subquery `Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`.. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193323/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `total_amount` in the second row of expected result was a mistake, this should do it:

```
SELECT date_a,
       a.id,
       SUM(IF(date_b <= date_a AND MONTH(date_b)=MONTH(date_a),amount,0)) AS total_amount 
    FROM a 
    INNER JOIN b 
       ON a.id=b.id 
GROUP BY date_a, a.id
ORDER BY date_a DESC;
```